Why the sizeof c in the last line = 10?
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
    
int main()
{
    short a = 1000;
    int b = 10000;
    long double c = 5.560000505012;
    
    cout << sizeof(c) - sizeof(b) << "\n"; // 12 ===> Tmam
    cout << sizeof(c) + sizeof(b) << "\n"; // 20 ===> Tmam
    cout << sizeof(a) * sizeof(c) << "\n"; // 32 ===> Tmam
    cout << a * (int)c << "\n"; // 5000
    
    cout << char( sizeof(c) * int(c) ) << "\n";
}

sizeof(c) is 16 in every line except the last line, where it is 10. Why?

You multiply the value 16 by itself (16 * 16) which result in the value 256. Which is too big to fit in an 8-bit integer like char usually is. And it's compiler-specific if char is signed or unsigned, so the range for two-complement systems are either -128 to 127, or for unsigned 0 to 255.

Unbelievably this seems to be an exercise that the OP has been given. Learning to program C++ should not be about using the language to set silly puzzles.

If you're expecting 'P' to correspond to ASCII 50, that's the hexadecimal representation of 80, which is 16 * 5. Cast to int instead.

why do you think it would be 10 ?!? Please include actual and expected output in the question

What makes you think it's not "16"? You could have given us the character that you actually got... Stackoverflow is a lot about telling people what you actually got, instead of just making vague claims.

@Someprogrammerdude int(c)  is 5, not 16. I think you read too fast.

@Someprogrammerdude "You multiply the value 16 by itself (16 * 16)" - no, actually the OP is multiplying the size of c (16) by the integer value of c (5), which is 16*5=80, which fits in a char (it is the letter 'P').

@463035818_is_not_an_ai sorry it's my first time using this site. I did the sizeof(c) in the last line and i expected it to be 16 but it gave me 10 that's where i'm confused. and the idea here was to get the output "P" but this is not the right way i think.

@PArika_ there is no possible way that sizeof(c) can ever be 10, and it can certainly never change value from one line to another. It is a fixed value at compile-time. Can you provide a screenshot of what you are actually seeing? You are likely just misinterpreting what you are seeing. char( sizeof(c) * int(c) ) produces 'P' as expected when I try it: https://onlinegdb.com/5I4SXC0fA

this works much better if you tell us what you see rather than only your conclusions because your conclusion are likely to be off. Thats why you should always show the output and say what you expect. [edit] the question to include that information. I still dont see why you think it would be 10, nothing is really obvious. Pretend your audience knows nothing about what you are doing.

we can only tell us where your line of reasoning is wrong if you tell us your line of reasoning

Ok guys because of my stupidity i thought "P" in ASCII has only the value of 50 but i found out it can have two values 50 and 80. that's the reason i thought sizeof(c) is 10 i'm sorry for taking your time.

@PArika_ "i thought "P" in ASCII has only the value of 50" - that is correct. "it can have two values 50 and 80" - no, it has only 1 value: 50 in decimal is 0x80 in hexadecimal (and is 120 in octal). They are just different representations of the same numeric value in memory.

@RemyLebeau: 50 in decimal is 0x32 in hexadecimal, which is 062 in octal. I believe you mixed up decimal and hexadecimal in your previous comment.

@AndreasWenzel yes, I meant 80 decimal and 0x50 hex. Good catch

The question you did ask cannot be answered. It is based on a false premise. The value of sizeof(c) is the same in the last line as in the lines above. Hence, there is no reason why it would be different in the last line. sizeof(c) is a compile-time constant. It cannot change.
Let's rephrase the question: "What happens in the last line?"
Frankly, I do not understand why you printed the previous lines but not what you need to understand the last line. Print the subexpressions:
#include <iostream>
        
int main()
{        
    // Do Not Edit Here
    short a = 1000;
    int b = 10000;
    long double c = 5.560000505012;
        
    std::cout << sizeof(c) << "\n";
    std::cout << int(c) << "\n";
    std::cout << sizeof(c) * int(c) << "\n";
    std::cout << char( sizeof(c) * int(c) ) << "\n";
}

Possible output is (it could be different, because width of long double is not fixed, only a minimum width is fixed, it can be wider):
16
5
80
P

sizeof(c) appears to be 16. c truncated to int evaluates to 5. Their product is 80, and in the used character encoding 80 results in 'P' to be printed when a char with that value is piped to std::cout.
When unsure about the integer value of a character, you can cast it to integer, but that would just give back the value from one line above.
There is no 10 involved.

I really like how dedicated you are for a simple question like this. the output I wanted was "P" I thought it can only be presented by "50" that's why I thought sizeof(c) was 10. but it turned out it can also be presented by "80" in the ASCII value.

@PArika_  I just added another note. If you are unsure about the value of a character, cast it to integer. std::cout << int('P');

@PArika_ the lesson to learn is to not do too big steps. Make tiny steps and when there is something you do not understand make even smaller steps. Don't assume things would be obvious or simple. You will get better not by being able to do bigger steps without thinking about it, but by knowing how to do the tiny steps and by knowing where to look.

I appreciate your respond really, have a nice day.

@PArika_ and btw "P" I thought it can only be presented by "50" that's why I thought sizeof(c) was 10" this is exactly the information that was missing from the question.

463035818_is_not_an_ai Yeah I was just rushing while writing the question. And Thanks for the advice.
